# Using Zumero to sync android application, change location of cache file

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, zumero

I am using Zumero to sync to a MS SQL server with my Android application, I have my SQLite db stored on the SD Card. When I run the sync it creates a cache file in the internal storage before updating the SQLite db. This is causing a internal storage issue and the operating system is deleting the cache file before updating the database due to running out of storage space. How can I force the app to use the SD Card for the cache file?

Answer (score 1):

I have it working by replacing

```
context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

with

```
context.getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the Zumero Java files directly as part of your application (look for `ZumeroClient.java`, etc. in the SDK), and edit the temp path being used. Compiles these into your app instead of using `zumero.jar` (you'll still need the appropriate `.so` libraries).

Out-of-the-box, Zumero uses the cache path provided by the Android context. You'll want to edit calls to `native_sync()`, and replace the last parameter with a path on the SD card.

e.g.

```
native_sync(databasePath, encryptionKey, serverURL, dbFile, authScheme,
            username, password, context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
```

would become

```
native_sync(databasePath, encryptionKey, serverURL, dbFile, authScheme, 
            username, password, myCacheDir);
```

Comment: I am using

'code'
public File getCacheFolder(Context context) {
  File cacheDir = null;
  if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
   cacheDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "cachefolder");
   if(!cacheDir.isDirectory()) {
    cacheDir.mkdirs();
   }
  }

  if(!cacheDir.isDirectory()) {
   cacheDir = context.getCacheDir(); //get system cache folder
  }


  return cacheDir;
 }
'code'

to get the directory.

How can get get it into the sync function?